# Ansible. Reconnecting the playbook connection

Tags: ansible

The server is being created. Initially there is user **root**, his password and **ssh** on **22** port (default).

There is a written **playbook**, for example, for a react application.

When you start **playbook**'a, everything is deployed for it, but before deploying, you need to configure the server to a minimum. Those. create a new **sudo** user, change the **ssh port** and copy the **ssh key** to the server. I think this is probably needed for any server.

After this setting, **yaml** appears in the **host_vars** directory with the variables for this server (*ansible_user, ansible_sudo_pass*, etc.)

For example, there are 2 roles: **initial-server, deploy-react-app**.
And the playbook itself (**main.yml**) for a specific application:

```
- name: Deploy
  hosts: prod
  roles:
  - role: initial-server
  - role: deploy-react-app
```

How to make it so that when you run `ansible-playbook main.yml`, the **initial-server** role is executed from the **root user with his password**, and the **deploy-react-app** role from the newly created one user and connection was **by ssh key** and not by password (root)? Or is it, in principle, not the correct approach?

Answer (score 1):

Note: using dashes (`-`) in role names is deprecated. I fixed that in my below example

Basically:

```yaml
- name: initialize server
  hosts: prod
  remote_user: root

  roles:
    - role: initial_server

- name: deploy application
  hosts: prod
  # That one will prevent to gather facts twice but is not mandatory
  gather_facts: false
  remote_user: reactappuser

  roles:
    - role: deploy_react_app
```

You could also set the `ansible_user` for each role vars in a single play:

```yaml
- name: init and deploy
  hosts: prod

  roles:
    - role: initial_server
      vars:
        ansible_user: root
    - role: deploy_react_app
      vars:
        ansible_user: reactappuser
```

There are other possibilities (using an `include_role` task). This really depends on your precise requirement.

Comment: Thanks! But what about the password? To **initial_server** need a **root password**, and for **deploy_react_app** - **ssh key** (which, in theory, will create a **initial_server**). Maybe I don't understand the concept well, but after all, the first launch must be with a **root password**, and all subsequent launches of **this playbook** with a **ssh key** from the user.

Comment: There are several solutions, one being to ask for the password interactively on the playbook command line (`-k`). The password should be used only when connection with a key is not possible (so only for the init step). You can also pass that as a var to your role (`ansible_ssh_pass`) but you should encrypt the content with ansible-vault in that case.